# convergence of an improper interval with two functions that are battling each other to see if the integral of the product converges

Tags: limits-without-lhopital, absolute-convergence

Boiled down, I have two functions of x and I need to know if the indefinite integral of their product converges.  In particular, if:

$$y=x\exp{-x^2}$$

then how can I show (if its true) that the indefinite integral, from minus to plus infinity converges to some value?

Comment: Avoid no-clue questions. You're here long enough to know you are required to show your attempts.

Comment: What if the answer you seek is not an area with which you have much insight or practice?  I had thought this was best solved by O(n) arguments, not straight calculus...but  I don't really know O(n) theory. I could see how this might be best handled via an O(n) argument, but that's the limit to my knowledge.

Comment: people used to spend hours with books. MSE can't replace books.

Comment: very different approach than used at stackoverflow.  There, many of the questions are of the form "I know how to create a class-specific method in C++, but am having trouble getting similar behavior in Python - anyone able to explain how its aligned?"  It's often a quick-question, crowd-sourced information sharing forum.

Comment: maybe there are some advantages because there is still a certain difference between these two domains. I can tell you, from my experience, even when you think you don' t see sth, try to leave it for the next morning and solve other problems in the meantime and study theory. When you relly don't have time, search the question here. This site should guide you and leave you your _aha_ moment to last longer. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should note that 
$$\int_a^bxe^{-x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}|_a^b.$$

Comment: Yes, pretty dim of me.